# How do I resize the controls automatically when form size is changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, uiview

I have two columns:

C1 and C2.

C1 has a fixed with of 250px and C2 should resize itself automatically. C2 contains gridview. So, if size changes to 1200px the gridview should automatically take up the 950px.

It's very easy in WPF by virtue of Grid control but how do I do that in Winforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do following:

- Put C1 inside the form.
- Set its width to 250 px.
- Set its `Dock` property to `Left` (or `Right`, up to you).
- Put C2 inside the form.
- Set its `Dock` property to `Fill`.
- Put your `GridView` inside C1.
- Set its `Dock` property to `Fill`.

Done.

As alternative you may use a `TableLayoutPanel` control (it works more or less like the WPF counterpart). Take a look to [this post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581424/windows-forms-app-autoscale-controls-with-form/9582015#9582015) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's better to let the controls resize themselves using the Anchor or Dock properties.

If for whatever reason you like to do that manually then you will need to handle the form resize event
and within it change the size and the position of gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Set C1.Width to 250 and C1.Dock to Left in the designer. Then set C2.Dock to Fill.

Comment: If I set C2 Dock to Fill, it takes up the whole form and my C1 goes behind C2.