# Scale the size of windows form and it's control

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, docking

I am working on a windows form application where I want my windows form to scale as I grow the size of the form. For instance,
[image: The tool so far I developed]

What I want here is when the user resizes it to bigger size, the controls should also resize with it. What's happening now is:
[image]

Can anyone please suggest a way to achieve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581424/windows-forms-app-autoscale-controls-with-form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at the Anchor-Property. What you want to do is achor the textboxes left, right and top. The elipsis-Buttons and compare button should be anchored top right. The large textbox should be anchored to all sides. And so on.

You won't need docking. If you also want to support environments with large fonts (larger dpi) you should use a table layout contron instead. In that case forget about the Anchors and set every Docking-property to fill.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I used the Anchor-Property and it worked just perfectly. :)